# What are the downstream side effects of converting an IEnumerable<T> to a ParallelQuery<T> with one degree of parallelism?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, plinq

What are the downstream costs of converting an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `ParallelQuery<T>` with one degree of parallelism?

For example:

```cs
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
          .Where(x => x <= target)
          .Select(x => x + 5); 

Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
          .AsParallel()
          .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
          .Where(x => x <= target)
          .Select(x => x + 5);
```

Its clear from the reference source that there will be some overhead (e.g. wrapping the `IEnumerable<T>` in a `ParallelEnumerableWrapper`).

From [ParallelEnumerable.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a38c5000be0d4b98445ef43d642614d0e8d8f82d/src/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs):

```cs
public static ParallelQuery AsParallel(this IEnumerable source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    return new ParallelEnumerableWrapper(source);
}

public static ParallelQuery<TSource> WithDegreeOfParallelism<TSource>(this ParallelQuery<TSource> source, int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (degreeOfParallelism < 1 || degreeOfParallelism > Scheduling.MAX_SUPPORTED_DOP)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(degreeOfParallelism));
    }

    QuerySettings settings = QuerySettings.Empty;
    settings.DegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelism;

    return new QueryExecutionOption<TSource>(
        QueryOperator<TSource>.AsQueryOperator(source), settings);
}
```

**Tests:**

In cases where the `degreeOfParallelism` passed to the extension method is greater than one, the behavior is as expected.

In tests where the `degreeOfParallelism` is equal to one, the behavior *looks* like the sequential implementation. Yet, I haven't been able to find examples of this pattern in the wild.

**Assuming:**

- The overhead incurred by calls to `AsParallel` and `WithDegreeOfParallelism` is acceptable.
- Enumerating the source collection does not introduce side effects.
- All subsequent operations defer execution and do not introduce side effects.
- There is a (*not unreasonable*) business case to prefer a single extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, with optional parameters for parallelism, over separate extension methods for the sequential and parallel implementations.

**Questions:**

1. Would this pattern introduce downstream costs to subsequent method calls?
2. If so, would these costs be predictable?

Comment: If you're worried about performance of your code, the best option is usually to measure it. Can't you do that?

Comment: @svick, I've measured the performance of this pattern in my existing code, and its acceptable for the current project. But what I'm trying to ask (though, perhaps not clearly) is what _types_ of costs are potentially being introduced by running a parallel query with only a single degree of parallelism? For example, PLINQ handles the merging of results from multiple threads; **could** this impact a downstream call in some predictable way?